# Why “echo -e a\ b\ c” interprets '\' escapes but “echo -e $(cat file)” does not?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

In the linux command line, one can use the syntax
`command1 $(command2)` to have the output of command2 be used as arguments
for command1. For example, if I have a file `test.txt` with content
`this\ is\ a\ test`, I can use (which in this case is nonsense)
`echo $(cat test.txt)`
to echo the output of `cat test.txt`. However, this interprets escape sequences
in a weird way: The output of the command
`echo -e this\ is\ a\ test` is `this is a test`, while the output of
`echo -e $(cat test.txt)` is `this\ is\ a\ test`. The escape sequences are not
interpreted as such. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Basically, you can't use the output of a command as argument**S** of another command reliably; quoting and escaping won't work, the words will be split. Only for a **single** argument you can use `command "$(command2)"` reliably

Comment: In one case the backslashes are syntax interpreted by the shell before `echo` is called; in the other they're literal data, passed to `echo` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set -x` to see the difference:

```
$ cat file
this\ is\ a\ test
$ set -x
$ echo -e this\ is\ a\ test
+ echo -e 'this is a test'
this is a test
$ echo -e 'this\ is\ a\ test'
+ echo -e 'this\ is\ a\ test'
this\ is\ a\ test
$ echo -e $(cat file)
++ cat file
+ echo -e 'this\' 'is\' 'a\' test
this\ is\ a\ test
```